# Displaying list of contacts/friends with previous chat history in smack

Tags: android, chat, openfire, smack

I am able to fetch the archived messages of a one-to-one chat by using MamManager class provided by Smack ([doc](https://github.com/igniterealtime/Smack/blob/master/documentation/extensions/mam.md)). But I have a requirement to display list of users along with latest message in a list similar to what whats app does.

[image]

Does anyone have any idea about how I can achieve this using smack & openfire? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Roster` class for fetching contacts in `Smack`. Also persist those contacts in your local database for offline support.

For implementing Whatsapp like contact import. You will have to fetch the contacts from your device and add them to your `Roster`. An ideal way of doing this would be to send the contacts via Rest-API and let the server add them to your `Roster`.

Once you initialize your connection object, you can attach a roster listener like so:

```
val connection:XMPPTCPConnection // assuming you have the connection object
val roster = Roster.getInstanceFor(connection)
// NOTE: You should attach your roster listener even before calling connect() on your connection object.
// This way you get the roster list whenever the connection connects!
roster.addRosterLoadedListener(object:RosterLoadedListener{
    override fun onRosterLoaded(roster: Roster?) {
        // Update your database
    }
    override fun onRosterLoadingFailed(exception: java.lang.Exception?) {
        // Handle error
    }
})
```

For persisting messages you will have to use local database(SQLite or some ORM)

Comment: Thanks. But if I store it in local database and user logs in new device it's not possible to sync the messages/contacts to new device right?

Comment: Also it would be great if you could share the code snippet of fetching contacts through Roster  class

Comment: Yes that is the case, but I would suggest that you start with single device scenario. As multi device gets far more complicated when you properly consider all use cases. especially when it comes to MultiUserChat. Moreover, you will have to store all the messages on your server for this to work. This is usually a security issue for many! :)

Comment: sure, give me some time, I will add some code too! :)

Comment: @AbhishekV I have added the code (It's in kotlin but fairly straightforward), let me know if you need any more help!

 :)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, it's been very helpful :)